# JSON Deserialization in c# receiving null values in all data members

Tags: c#, json, rest, serialization, json-deserialization

Below is the valid JSON which my service is returning upon invocation:

```
[{
   "CCRQ": "2006/1/26 0:00:00",
   "CLXH": "CA6510B1",
   "CarBodyColor": "color"
}]
```

Below is my code containing datamembers:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember(Name = "CCRQ")]
    public string CCRQ { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "CLXH")]
    public string CLXH { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "CarBodyColor")]
    public string CarBodyColor { get; set; }
}
```

However I am making a request to service and receiving null in all data members.

```
public static Response MakeRequest(string requestUrl)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));

        object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
        Response jsonResponse = objResponse as Response;
        return jsonResponse;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting null in all the attributes?

Comment: Is the 'objResponse' variable null or not? But anyway the problem lies probably in "typeof(Response)" sice the JSON is of type 'List<Response>' and not 'Response'.

Comment: From your use of `[DataContract]` I'm going to assume you're web service is using WCF. Why are you creating a `HttpWebRequest`? You could add a service reference to your project and all the deserialization is handled for you.

Comment: @Julo, issue was due to absence of list<>. issue has been resolved. thanks :)

Comment: @Chris Pickford, thanks, the service is not using WCF, i believe it is Java based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is an array with 1 object content. For what I can see, your deserializer expects an object.

try as response

```
{
   "CCRQ": "2006/1/26 0:00:00",
   "CLXH": "CA6510B1",
   "CarBodyColor": "color"
}
```

or cast response to `objResponse as List<Response>`